# What will be the time trigger value based on the Business hour in salesforce?

Tags: entitlements, milestone

Salesforce: I have the `Business hours` set from `Mon-Fri (10 AM to 7 PM)`, weekend no business hours. The SLA for one of the my process in 10 business days, **What values do I need to put in the Time trigger minutes ?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

((19-10) * 60) * 10) ?

((EOB-SOB) * MPH) * NOBD)

End of Business day, (19:00 or 7PM),

Start of Business day, (10:00 AM),

Minutes per hour, (Always 60),

Number of business days (10 in your sample)

If you want to exclude Holidays, these can be created in setup as well, and you need to link them to whichever business hours they are for.

Comment: Could you please guide on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060408/how-the-target-response-date-is-calculate-in-an-entiltment-process-milestone ?

Comment: hey as per formula, does it not get calculated for 9 business days only ? How you consider the 19 as End-Of Business ?