# How the target response Date is calculate in an Entiltment Process Milestone?

Tags: apex, entitlements, milestone

I am new to the `Entitlement Process` and `Milestones` using the `OOTB` implementations. In my org, two `business hours` (1 for SLA and 1 for OLA) set with different timezone. Each business hours configured to work `9 AM to 6 PM`.

Extending the question from link : [What will be the time trigger value based on the Business hour in salesforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880366/what-will-be-the-time-trigger-value-based-on-the-business-hour-in-salesforce/45898987#45898987) .

I have some SLA which has 5 days of deadline. As per formula `((EOB-SOB) * MPH) * NOBD)`, I need to get clarification on below if its correct:

```
EOB = Assume 5 days deadline, so 14/05/17
SOB = Today, so 09/05/17
MPH = 60 minutes
NOB = 5, What do I need to consider here? As No. of business day means 5 days
here, as 5 days of deadline?? Please clarify.
```

One thing which is observed for 5 days business: as per formula 5*60*5=1500 or 5*60*9 (no of business hours)=2700. As per 2nd logic I implemented, but OOTB not showing 5 days, its only showing the 2 days why ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, regarding: [What will be the time trigger value based on the Business hour in salesforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880366/what-will-be-the-time-trigger-value-based-on-the-business-hour-in-salesforce/45898987#45898987)
EOB, stood for end of Business day, so 19:00 or 7 PM
SOB, was 10 AM in your sample

I have cleared up my original answer on that question as well.

### Current question

Target Response (Days) showing 2 for 45 hours....

Ah, eh, yes tricky and often asked for. The 2 is simple 45/24 and then rounded off...

It is not business days!

There are some ideas on the [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) for this, but for now this is how it is.

Comment: Right, I have two separate business hours for SLA and OLA. I think it will clear my doubts now. You're such a nice person I come across. +1 upvote

Comment: Ok Now I understood. No. of business hours (9) * 60 * No of days deadline (10) = 2700, then why OOTB target Response (hours) will show correct, but Target Response (Days) will show as per 24 hours. Am I right ?

Comment: Good, Am I correct on the above posts ? Can we show two milestone tracker on the Case feed if two milestones are triggered at the same time ?

Comment: You can have multiple milestones at the same time, but the tracker component only once, still in the tracker you can also work with mutliple ones.
Now for using different business hours on one case...
[How Business Hours Work in Entitlement Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_business_hours.htm&type=5)